# Getting the id from anchor tag with PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I tried to get the id from my anchor. Is there a way to fetch it with PHP?

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#dpd-'.$model->idDpd->id_dpd.'" id='.$model->idDpd->id_dpd.'role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$model->name.'</a>
```

I used DOMDocument::getElementById to fetch the id of the anchor. I'm not sure if there's any better way (I'm using Yii2 framework btw):

```
ob_start();
include 'cabang.php';
$result = ob_get_clean();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc -> load($result);

// We need to validate our document before refering to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;

$result = $doc->getElementById('$model->idDpd->id_dpd');

$query = Cabang::find()-> where(['id_dpd'=>$result])->all();

//other code goes here
```

The above code give this error : `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)`

I specified the anchor with its respective id for fetching purpose. When an anchor with specific "id_dpd" is chosen, it will then show the details based on the chosen anchor id. Is the only way to fetch it with AJAX ?

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that any of your anchors actually has the id value `$model->idDpd->id_dpd`. Apart from that, I don’t understand what you are even trying to do here.

Comment: If you want to, on the server side, generate the correct content when one of those links is clicked, then those links should maybe rather use the query string to transport the necessary info, than the fragment identifier. The latter is a purely client-side construct, and does not even get send to the server.

Comment: `134217728` is 132MB which is very much for a public website request. Maybe you load more data than you need. A little finding: You have quotes here which are wrong: `$doc->getElementById('$model->idDpd->id_dpd');` I think it should be `$doc->getElementById('#dpd-' . $model->idDpd->id_dpd);`.

Comment: @04FS Hi, thanks for your response. I'm actually trying to get the value of the anchor id that is assigned according to the id_dpd. The anchor acts as menu. Then, I'll use the value to generate a details from the database on the the anchor menu's id value. Can you give me the example of the said query string to transport the necessary info? I'm unfamiliar with using query string in anchor tag.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Hi Dan, thank you for your correction. Yes I guess I shouldn't include "cabang.php" as it is the problem why its memory is exhausted. I just want to load the current file with `DomDocument->load()`, maybe I should use `DomDocument->load(dir(__FILE__))` instead.

Comment: I think the better way to meet my purpose is not using PHP but AJAX/Javascript instead. Trying to fetch the value with pure PHP just make it complicated, am I right? Sorry I'm still learning web devolpment.